# Array with type <Name> not working, Error Cannot resolve Name to a Type

Tags: java, arrays, object, types

I'm trying to write a program that let's me enter multiple Objects of the same Class, Drinks in my Case, into an Array.
When trying to create the Array, i can't set the Type to my Object. I feel like i'm missing something very obvious, i'd appreciate any help!

This is the code i have so far. The names are in german, hope that's not a problem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class KellnerGetraenkeliste {

// Erstellen der Attribute
private String kunde;
private int anzahl;
private String getraenk;

private KellnerGetraenkeliste(String kunde, int anzahl, String getraenk) {
    super();
    this.kunde = kunde;
    this.anzahl = anzahl;
    this.getraenk = getraenk;
}

ArrayList<getraenk> getraenkeListe = new ArrayList<getraenk>();
```

}

Comment: Did you mean `ArrayList<getraenk> getraenkeListe` to be an array of `String`s? It may have to be `ArrayList<String> getraenkeListe`. Otherwise, `getraenk` should be a type (clas/interface/...)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele getrank is supposed to be a class with different attributes. I'm now realizing that i obviously have to create that class first. After having done that, i should be able to create a class of objects, right? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: That's right. The class must be created first.

Answer (score 0):

The generic specified between  square brackets  has to be a class, not a variable name.
In your case it should be a `String` such as :

```
ArrayList<String> getraenkeListe = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Note that it would be better to declare an interface as declared type and to use the diamond operator for the instantiation to not repeat the generic such as :

```
List<String> getraenkeListe = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks so much! If my Object Getraenk now has different attributes though, i won't be able to input those into the list if it is just of the type string, right? So i would have to create another class with those attributes, and then use the name of that class as the generic?